# no type named ‘pointer’ in struct std::iterator_traits<...>

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, iterator-traits

Here are the fragments of my linked_list template :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template < class >
struct linked_list {
    struct iterator_base : public std::iterator< std::bidirectional_iterator_tag , int >
    {  
        typename std::iterator_traits< iterator_base >::pointer operator -> () const {
            std::cerr << __func__ ; 
            return nullptr ; } ;
    };
    using difference_type = typename std::iterator_traits< iterator_base >::difference_type ;
} ;

int main ()
{
    int * inullptr = linked_list< int >::iterator_base().operator->() ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

When I leave `using...` line uncommented, the code doesn't compile.

g++5.4 :

```
list2.cxx:105:66: error: no type named ‘pointer’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<linked_list<int>::iterator_base<(linked_list<int, std::allocator<int> >::constantness)1u> >’
          typename std::iterator_traits< iterator_base >::pointer operator -> () const { return &( to_obj_node( current_node_ ) -> object() ) ; }
```

icpc :

```
list.cxx(105): error: incomplete type is not allowed typename std::iterator_traits< iterator_base >::pointer operator -> () const { return &( to_obj_node( current_node_ ) -> object() ) ; }
```

Without that line all compiles fine.

the question is : What happens, when i'm commenting `using difference_type = typename std::iterator_traits< iterator >::difference_type;` in above code ( only with such changes code compiles ).?

==========================================================================
[res.on.functions/2.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.functions)

> 2. In particular, the ***effects are undefined*** in the following cases:...
>
>    5. if an incomplete type ([basic.types]) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically
>         allowed for that component.

and historical [discussion](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#287) on that.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What is `node< T >`?

Comment: Do you `#include <iterator>` ?

Comment: @Barry, provided.

Comment: @GreenTree That example isn't particularly minimal. Also it compiles so I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: @Barry, i edited question.

Comment: [MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8afcf83bab8de18). To instantiate `std::iterator_traits< iterator_base >`, you instantiate `iterator_base` which again attempts to instantiate `std::iterator_traits< iterator_base >` and blows up.

Comment: @T.C., why then without "using ..." line iterator_base becomes instantiated.?

Comment: "incomplete type is not allowed" is pretty clear to me. What's unclear about that?

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf, "incomplete type is not allowed typename std::iterator_traits< iterator_base >::pointer operator -> () const" and only with using line.

Comment: @GreenTree: The **incomplete type** there is `iterator_base`. It's incomplete at this point because this point is in the middle of its class definition. Inside the definition of a class (except within bodies of member functions), that class is incomplete, not yet completely known, of unknown size.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, but there, at the operator definition, iterator_base isn't required to be complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is that the type `std::iterator_traits< iterator_base >` is still incomplete and at the time that you want to access `::pointer` does not yet provide that `pointer` member.

The class `std::iterator_traits<iterator_base>` is being instantiated by `typename std::iterator_traits< iterator_base >::difference_type`, because it's used on the left side of a `::`, and because it has not yet been instantiated. This triggers the instantiation of `linked_list<int>::iterator_base` because the body of `iterator_traits` uses that class to define its various member typedefs - for example the instantiation could happen at a line that looks like `typedef typename Iterator::value_type value_type;` in the Standard library.

What follows is the use of `std::iterator_traits< iterator_base >::pointer` in your nested class. This time, `iterator_traits<iterator_base>` is already being instantiated, so nothing is done, and `::pointer` is searched. But since that wasn't declared yet, it can't found.

Note that when you comment-out the `using` line, nothing in the code will instantiate the nested class body anymore (the body of members of class templates are "lazily instantiated"), so this can't be a measure for or against the validity of the constructs inside of that nested class body.

Comment: give some body to the operator and int main() { auto iptr=linked_list< int >::iterator_base().operator -> () ; return 0; }. compiles perfectly with commented line.

Comment: or template list<int> ;

Comment: @GreenTree I have explained why it fails for your case and explained why it doesn't fail if you comment-out the `using` line. The reason why it actually works to instantiate `iterator_base` is, that at the time you are inside of the body of `iterator_base`, you can already lookup `iterator_base::pointer`, `value_type` etc (define by the base class). And at the time you do `iterator_traits< iterator_base >::pointer`, it will instantiate `iterator_traits<iterator_base>`, and all it wants is to access those typedefs, which is possible at that point.

Comment: You basically have a case of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#287 . I think that the intended model is that this should work, however even the C++ experts in that discussion had different understandings of the mechanics. And as they note, at least back 15 years ago some compilers had problems with this.

Comment: Note that [res.on.functions]/2.5 bans this regardless of what Core says.

Comment: please, add both links to your answer (links to core and to std).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iterator>

struct OK_1: std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, int> {};
using Pointer_1 = typename std::iterator_traits<OK_1>::pointer;

struct Nah
{
    using Pointer_nah = typename std::iterator_traits<Nah>::pointer;    //!
};

auto main() -> int
{}
```

At the point of declaration of `Pointer_nah`, the type `Nah` is an incomplete type.

`iterator_traits` has to look inside that type in order to find its `pointer` definition.

But that, recursively, requires the definition of `iterator_traits<Nah>`.

And so on.

But, main point: `Nah` is incomplete at the point where `Pointer_nah` is declared. **Incomplete** means that the class is not fully known. In particular its size is not known here, so it can't be passed to `sizeof`.

I suspect that that's the reason why one of your compilers exclaimed,

> **”** error: incomplete type is not allowed

Comment: have you tried to compile my example with uncommented and commented  "using" line.?
why then in second case the code compiles.?

Comment: @GreenTree: In a template you can have all sorts of things that wouldn't compile if they were used. As soon as you use them, the compiler complains. Somehow the `difference_type` declaration, which uses  `iterator_base`, is itself used if it's present. I don't know why, but you can experiment with other ways of actually using `iterator_base`. As soon as you do, it blows up. :)

Comment: see history of question editions, all code from that ( like for( auto each : list ) ) compiles.

Comment: Sorry, I don't grok that comment.